# virtual and override how to use those?

Tags: c#, class, overriding, virtual

hello i wrote two simple classes

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Kus
{
    class Program : Class1
    {
        public Program()
        {}
        public override void findtheflyingdistance(out int x)
        {   x=0;
            Random r = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                int z = r.Next(100, 500);
                x += x + z;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Kuş" + x);

        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x;
            Program pg = new Program();
            pg.findtheflyingdistance(out x);
            Class1 C1 = pg;
            C1.findtheflyingdistance(out x);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Kus
{
    class Class1
    {
        public Class1(){}
        public virtual void findtheflyingdistance(out int x)
        {   x=0;
            int z=200;
            x += x + z;
            Console.WriteLine("Leylek" +x);

        }
    }
}
```

as i understand override method override the virtual method. When i create two instance in the main Program class. findtheflyingdistance(out int x) in Program class worked for two instance but when i did method findtheflyingdistance(out int x) virtual in two clasess. Each instance work with own classes. So i dont understand the logic behind the scene. Why do we write virtual methods? if we want to override a method we can do override and non-virtual method that will be overriden already.

Comment: `"we can do override and non-virtual method that will be overriden already"` - You can?  Not according to MSDN: "By default, methods are non-virtual. You cannot override a non-virtual method." (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx)

Comment: if some comment help you to understand it and you are finish with this question accept it !

Answer (score 1):

**Virtual** allows you to override a method which is defined in the base class. In other words, it extends the implementation of the method in the derived class.

[this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153.aspx) would be an interesting read.

[this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6162547/3436942) answer also gives a short example, which i have copied below for handiness:

> The virtual keyword is used to modify a method, property, indexer or
>   event declaration, and allow it to be overridden in a derived class.
>   For example, this method can be overridden by any class that inherits
>   it: Use the new modifier to explicitly hide a member inherited from a
>   base class. To hide an inherited member, declare it in the derived
>   class using the same name, and modify it with the new modifier.
>
> This is all to do with polymorphism. When a virtual method is called
>   on a reference, the actual type of the object that the reference
>   refers to is used to decide which method implementation to use. When a
>   method of a base class is overridden in a derived class, the version
>   in the derived class is used, even if the calling code didn't "know"
>   that the object was an instance of the derived class. For instance:

```
public class Base { public virtual void SomeMethod() { } }

public class Derived : Base { public override void SomeMethod() { } }
  ...

 Base b = new Derived(); 
b.SomeMethod();
```

> will end up calling
>   Derived.SomeMethod if that overrides Base.SomeMethod.
>
> Now, if you use the new keyword instead of override, the method in the
>   derived class doesn't override the method in the base class, it merely
>   hides it. In that case, code like this:

```
 public class Base { public virtual void SomeOtherMethod() { } }

 public class Derived : Base { public new void SomeOtherMethod() { } }

 ...


 Base b = new Derived();
 Derived d = new Derived();
 b.SomeOtherMethod(); 
d.SomeOtherMethod();
```

> Will first call
>   Base.SomeOtherMethod , then Derived.SomeOtherMethod . They're
>   effectively two entirely separate methods which happen to have the
>   same name, rather than the derived method overriding the base method.
>
> If you don't specify either new or overrides, the resulting output is
>   the same as if you specified new, but you'll also get a compiler
>   warning (as you may not be aware that you're hiding a method in the
>   base class method, or indeed you may have wanted to override it, and
>   merely forgot to include the keyword).
>
> An overriding property declaration may include the sealed modifier.
>   Use of this modifier prevents a derived class from further overriding
>   the property. The accessors of a sealed property are also sealed.

Comment: gotta learn virtual, override and new. Well i need to start reading msdn links. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @BeratEmreNebioglu it's probably  one of the best sources of info let's be honest here, you can't get more official than mdsn for most stuff!

Comment: sure msdn page has really good stuff. i started reading c# book recently. there is sone new concepts compare to java.