# Run-time type vs compile-time type in C#

Tags: c#

What is the difference between a run-time type and a compile-time type in C# and what implications exist regarding virtual method invocation?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Lets say we have two classes `A` and `B` declared as follows:

```
internal class A
{
    internal virtual void Test() => Console.WriteLine("A.Test()");
}

internal class B : A
{
    internal override void Test() => Console.WriteLine("B.Test()");
}
```

`B` inherits from `A` and overrides the method `Test` which prints a message to the console.

---

> What is the difference between a run-time type and a compile-time type in C#

Now lets consider the following statement:

`A test = new B();`

- **at compile time:** the compiler only knows that the variable `test` is of the type `A`. He does not know that we are actually giving him an instance of `B`. Therefore the compile-type of `test` is `A`.
- **at run time:** the type of `test` is known to be `B` and therefore has the run time type of `B`

---

> and what implications exist regarding virtual method invocation

Consider the following code statement:

`((A)new B()).Test();`

We are creating an instance of `B` casting it into the type `A` and invoking the `Test()` method on that object. The compiler type is `A` and the runtime type is `B`.

When the compiler wants to resolve the `.Test()` call he has a problem. Because `A.Test()` is `virtual` the compiler can not simply call `A.Test` because the instance stored might have overridden the method.

The compile itself can not determine which of the methods to call `A.Test()` or `B.Test()`. The method which is getting invoked is determined by the runtime and not "hardcoded" by the compiler.

Comment: Thank you.   Thank you for taking the time to type our a very clear answer.  Much appreciated.