# Polymorphism - Method overriding and overloading not clear

Tags: java

I am learning polymorphism but not able to understand how it works

When I try to create an object `Car car = new Audi();`, overriding prints "This is Audi". But with same object I am not able to call `first(int x, int y)` of `Audi` class... I am able to call only `Car` class `first()`.

Overriding prints the Audi method, Overloading prints Car method.. when calling with same object..

> Class Car

```
class Car {
   public void carName() {
      System.out.println("Parent of car");
   }

   public int first() {
      System.out.println("Base - Parent");
      return 2;
   }
}
```

> Class BMW

```
class BMW extends Car {
   public void carName() {
      System.out.println("This is BMW");
   }
   public int first(int x) {
      System.out.println("BMW override");
      return x;
   }
}
```

> Class Audi

```
class Audi extends BMW {
   public void carName() {
      System.out.println("This is Audi");
   }
   public int first(int x, int y) {
      System.out.println("AUdi Override");
      return x;
   }
}
```

> Class PloyMor

```
public class PolyMor extends Audi {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      Car car = new Audi();
      car.carName();
      car.first();
   }
}
```

Comment: why does Audi extend BMW, and not Car?

Comment: The methods `first()` and `first(int, int)` are completely different, unrelated methods. To the compiler, them having the same name is mostly irrelevant. And, since you don't have a `first(int, int)` method on `Car`, the only one available to you when using an object which you declared as a `Car` is the no-argument version.

Comment: @OldProgrammer i tried that too..but the output is still same..even if Audi extends Car, car object prints Audi class carName() method but not able to call for method overloading..still able to call only first() method of Car..

Comment: @resueman oh ok, i think i am getting it slowly..thanks!

Comment: Audi extending BMW makes no sense, you are overloading first() method with first(int x, int y) and it is defined in a specific car model, Car itself doesn’t have that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Important: I am assuming that class `BTW` extends `Car` not `Audi` (which would makes no sense IMO).

---

> But with same object i am not able to call first(int x, int y) of Audi class.

You need to distinguish between *variable* type and *value* (object) type. In case of

```
Car car = new Audi();
```

variable type is `Car` while type of object it holds is `Audi`.

You need to realize that compiler doesn't *assume* what is the value of variable. It applies same rules as if it was parameter of method like

```
void someMethod(Car car){
    //do something with `car`
}
```

where inside of that method we don't know if it will be used with `someMethod(new Audi());` or `someMethod(new BMW());`.

So which methods can be **safely** invoked via `car` variable inside `someMethod` body? Only those which are *guaranteed* to be implemented (to appear) in **all** objects which can be used as method arguments. If that method would let us write `car.first(1, 2);` it will work for scenario like `someMethod(new Audi())` but will fail for `someMethod(new BMW())` because BMW doesn't have `first(int x, int y)` method.

Answer (score 1):

Calling a method depends on the compile-type rather than the runtime type.

```
Car car = new Audi();
^               ^
compile-type    runtime type
```

**Compiled Type vs Runtime Type:**
[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37630983/run-time-type-vs-compile-time-type-in-c-sharp)

Credit: @duffymo

Let's say we have

```
A test = new B();
```

- at compile time: the compiler only knows that the variable test is of the type A. He does not know that we are actually giving him an instance of B. Therefore the compile-type of test is A.
- at run time: the type of test is known to be B and therefore has the run time type of B

Since compiler does not know what type will be stored at runtime it only allows us to call methods of Class A

**Solution:**

If you want to call methods from instantiated type do this
then you will be able to access method `first(int x, int y)`

```
Audi car = new Audi();
car.carName();
car.first(); // Original Method
car.first(3, 3); // Overloading
```

**Output:**

```
This is Audi
Base - Parent
AUdi Overload
```

P.S Like OldProgrammer mentioned Audi should extend Car instead of BMW

Comment: I would use the terms "compile type" and "runtime" types.   The compile type is Car; the runtime type of the car reference is Audi.

Answer (score 1):

It would have worked if you had another method defined in the base class like follows:

```
public int first(int a, int b) {
    System.out.println("Base - Parent");
    return 2;
}
```

As the final object you are trying to create is an object of class `Car`, it only has the methods from the `Car` class which if are present in `Audi` class, will override the methods in `Car` class.

Answer (score 1):

You are not overriding first from `Car` in `Audi`, because the signatures are different.

The signature includes the method name, parameters, and throws clause.

The method `first()` from `Car` takes no arguments.

In `Audi` it takes two ints as arguments.  Not the same.

Even your simple hierarchy is not a good design.  You are having problems because your implementation is bad.

Try this:

```
public abstract class Car {
    private String name;
    private int id;

    public Car(String name, int id) { 
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() { return this.name; }
    public int getId() { return this.id; }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();
        cars.add(new Audi());
        cars.add(new Bmw());
        System.out.println(cars);
    }
}

class Audi extends Car {
    public Audi() {
        super("Audi", 1);
    }
}

class Bmw extends Car {
    public Bmw() {
       super("BMW", 2);
    }
}
```