# Difference between creating objects with master/sub class "Cat cat1 = new Cat(); vs Animal cat2 = new Cat();"

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

(First time posting in Stackoverflow, so If I did it wrong, I am sorry =(   )

What is the difference between creating an object from its class or the class its inheriting from?

I made this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Cat cat1 = new Cat();

        Animal cat2 = new Cat();


        Animal[] animals = new Animal[2];
        animals[0] = new Cat();
        animals[1] = new Dog();

        cat1.MakeSound();
        cat2.MakeSound();

        Console.WriteLine();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    class Animal
    {
        public virtual void MakeSound()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Animal makes a sound");
        }
    }

    class Dog : Animal
    {
        public override void MakeSound()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Dog barks");
        }
    }

    class Cat : Animal
    {
        public override void MakeSound()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cat meows");
        }
    }
```

As you can see I made an Animal class with one method "MakeSound", I then made two classes "Cat" and "Dog" which inherit from the Animal class and also override the default Animal class. Nothing weird so far, just some basic Inheritance and Polymorphism. But then when its time to create the objects a question arose. I made the objects in 2 different ways:

```
Cat cat1 = new Cat();

Animal cat2 = new Cat();
```

One is made with the Cat class and the other is made with the superclass, the Animal class. Is *There* a big difference between these two? I could see some difference in that you would be able to create lists with more than one animal:

```
 Animal[] animals = new Animal[2];
 animals[0] = new Cat();
 animals[1] = new Dog();
```

And I guess it wouldnt go to use these in methods that have cats or dog objects as parameters, but other than that. Is the difference that big?

Answer (score 0):

The difference becomes obvious when you have methods on your subclasses that aren't declared on your superclass:

```
class Animal {
  public abstract void MakeSound();
}
class Cat : Animal {
  public override void MakeSound() {
    this.Meow();
  }

  public void Meow() {
    Console.WriteLine("meow.");
  }
}

Cat cat = new Cat();
Animal animal = new Cat();
cat.MakeSound(); // works
cat.Meow(); // works
animal.MakeSound(); // works
animal.Meow(); // compile error

Animal animal2 = cat1; // works
Cat cat2 = animal; // compile error
```

Useful resources:

- [Run-time type vs compile-time type in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37630983/run-time-type-vs-compile-time-type-in-c-sharp)
- [What is polymorphism, what is it for, and how is it used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031273/what-is-polymorphism-what-is-it-for-and-how-is-it-used)
- [What is Polymorphism?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/418872/what-is-polymorphism)
- [Understanding polymorphism and interface in Java](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/315632/understanding-polymorphism-and-interface-in-java)

Comment: aa ok, so I guess there are some minor differences like that. It goes back to what code is available in what class. Thanks! super helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I can see your confusion. If this helps:

> I made the objects in 2 different ways

Actually, you didn't make the cats in two different ways. You made the cats in the same way: `new Cat()`. So you created two new cats.

> One is made with the Cat class and the other is made with the superclass, the Animal class

Not quite. You've *created* them both using the subclass of `Cat`. Not the superclass.

You then *refer* to `cat2` using a superclass variable. That doesn't alter the fact it was created as a `Cat`. It still behaves like a `Cat` object.

Extending your metaphor into real life: if you had a cat in front of you, but decide to call it an "animal"... It'll still make a noise like a cat.

### Edit

Picking up on your comment that `Animal cat = new Cat()` means it's "created" as a cat. Important to realise, that's not correct.

The `cat` is still a `new Cat()` object. You're just deciding to view it as an animal. It still behaves like a Cat.

You *are* correct that if `Cat` has some extra methods, you won't be able to call them from an `Animal` reference. But crucially, understand that those methods *still exist inside* the cat object you've created.

Just to prove this point: if you "cast" the variable back to type `Cat`, you'd immediately have access to those methods. In fact this links nicely into what @knittl was saying: let's pretend that `Cat` has an extra method `Meow()`

```cs
Animal catTreatedAsAnimal = new Cat();

catTreatedAsAnimal.MakeSound() // still behaves like a cat.
catTreatedAsAnimal.Meow(); // but, this won't compile, because we're pretending it's just an Animal instead of a Cat.

Cat definitelyCat = catTreatedAsAnimal as Cat; // Cast, i.e. change the reference type (but it's still the same object in memory)
definitelyCat.Meow(); // this now works.
```

TL;DR. The Cat is always a `Cat`, even if you declare the variable as `Animal`. But you need the *variable* to be declared as `Cat`, if you want to access those cat-specific methods.

Further reading on Casting: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions

Comment: Ok, so if I understand it right now. I created cat objects in both examples and they both behave in almost the exact same way. The difference is in Encapsulation and Inheritance. The first cat created with "Animal" will be able to use all animals methods/attributes. The second cat created with "Cat" as reference will also be able to use all Animals methods/attributes. The difference is if the cat method declares some more methods/attributes. The cat will be able to use them, but not the cat created from Animal.

Comment: Yes... Although throw away your idea of "created from Animal". It's _still_ created from Cat. in fact, if you were to "cast" your variable type from Animal back to Cat, you'd still be able to call the Cat methods too. I will update my post to mention this.