# My method in child class does not get called

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, oop, inheritance

I have two classes, one of them is **Base** and the other is **Child**, and both of them have the method **Print** with the same name and signature. These are my classes:

```
class Base
{
    public void Print() { Console.WriteLine("Base"); }
}

class Child : Base
{
    public void Print() { Console.WriteLine("Child"); }
}
```

now, I'm trying to create an instance of Child and assign it to Base like this:

```
Base obj = new Child();
obj.Print();
```

my question is, why does it show me "Base" in output? I expect to see "Child" in output because my instance is of type Child.

Comment: You need to use `virtual` and `override`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6162547/2791540) for examples.

Comment: This is a common mistake, however if you look closely at the compiler output you should be getting a CS0108 warning about not using the new keyword when declaring Child's Print method. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0108?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0108)

Comment: Eric Lippert wrote a bit about why C# allows non-virtual dispatch here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/method-hiding-apologia

Answer (score 1):

You must mark the Print method of the Base instance as virtual so that its derived classes can override that method.
In your example:

```
class Base
{
    public virtual void Print() { Console.WriteLine("Base"); }
}

class Child : Base
{
    public override void Print() { Console.WriteLine("Child"); }
}
```

If you try now this code

```
 Base obj = new Child()
 obj.Print()
```

You should see in the Console

```
Child
```